# Learn mathematical thinking with open source (SageMath, GeoGebra, ....)

Tags: self-learning, computer-algebra-systems, sagemath

Hi do you know a good introduction about mathematical thinking using opensource software like Sage math and/or geogebra ?

I found http://abstract.ups.edu/download/aata-20170805-sage-8.0.pdf but I think it's a little bit overwhelming ...do you know something else ?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice book that a team of authors wrote and released under Creative Commons license, first in French, and now translated to English and to German.

- Calcul mathématique avec Sage / Mathematical computation with Sage.
  http://sagebook.gforge.inria.fr/

Comment: Just  perfect i'm french :) Thanks !